# "Who was" or "Who were"?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Which of the following is correct ?

> Who **were** these buildings designed by?

Or

> Who **was** these buildings designed by?

Does *were/was* refer to "these buildings" or "who"?

Comment: The question is usually in the same form as the answer. So the answer might be  these buildings were designed by Lutyens - the subject of the verb is the buildings.                 So, the question is "Who were these buildings designed by>".     You could also say "Who was the architect who designed these buildings?    Lutyens was the architect.

Comment: Or rephrasing can help: These *buildings were* designed by whom?

Comment: In your highlighted sentences, the grammatical number of *was/were* should agree with the number of *designers*, not the number of *buildings*.

Answer (score 2):

"**Who were** these buildings designed by?" Would be correct.

The subject is "buildings", and "were" is the verb.

Comment: If these buildings are supposed to be designed by one person...